# Print out Certain elements in a List using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to build a web-scraper for Linkedin using Python and Selenium. I am trying to print out the title, but the output is only showing an empty list and I'm not sure why. I have tried printing all elements in the list and using items.text.replace() to replace the common outputs, however, the output was still all elements. I have also tried printing the parent divs, but the output is still an empty list.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#search
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ember16']/input").send_keys("Steve Jobs")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ember16']/input").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#result count
resultCount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ember64']/div/h3")
print("\n" + str(resultCount.text))

#printing
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember64"]/div/ul')

for items in results:
    print(str(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember552"]/div/div[2]/p[1]'))+"\n")
```

Here is the output:

```
About 43,000 results
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Is there anyway to specify the element to print while iterating through a list?**

EDIT:
Here is a minimal reproducible example of this code:

```
# search url
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Steve%20Jobs&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER'
driver.get(url)

# print job title
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember64"]/div/ul')
for items in results:

    print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember552"]/div/div[2]/p[1]'))
```

Here is the output:

```
[]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What link\URL are you using?

Comment: @Mike67 I use https://www.linkedin.com/login Then it automatically signs in using .send_keys() and .click(). The link before is what i put in driver.get() and once I search, I get to https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Steve%20Jobs&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER

Comment: What does driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember552"]/div/div[2]/p[1]').text print out?

Comment: @arundeepchohan It prints an empty list, which would be, "[]"

Comment: @Greg Check recent edits. I did not include the signing-in code in the example because I found it unnecessary.

Comment: What does print(items) do rn?

Comment: You might wanna do results.find_elements_by_xpath() instead.

Comment: @arundeepchohan results.find_elements_by_xpath() has the same as before and print(items.text) prints all elements/

Comment: Can you put what items.text prints out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@class,'search-results__list list-style-none')]/li")))
```

and for tittle you can use below xpath along with gettext()

```
//*[contains(@class,'subline-level-1 t-14')]
```

Contains() used in xpath to find out webelement with partial text.
and explict wait can be used with many conditions i have used one of them above. It is good practice to use wait before finding any webelement.
More details for selenium wait ref https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
xpath functions-https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35413_01/doc.722/e35419/dev_xpath_functions.htm#autoId12
Xpath shows all list to me:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, it printed an empty list as in the same output as before. I am a novice in selenium and I would like to know what contains() does. I'm assuming it finds the xpath containing that class name but I'm not too sure.